# Does Atelier Totori Plus have the Music DLC already in it

Tags: ps-vita, atelier-totori

The original Atelier Totori had a Model Viewer, Past Game Music and Cory, Iksel and Ceci Party Characters as DLC. From what I've read, the Party Character's DLC is standard in Atelier Totori Plus and it seems like the Model Viewer is standard too as in the Extra Menu there is a Model Viewer (that's as far as I went in when I started the game because I was checking for my Angel and Imp Costumes for Totori).

I'm wondering if the Music DLC that you normally had to get separate in the original Atelier Totori is found in Atelier Totori Plus.

NOTE: The DLC adds music from previous Atelier games which can be set as alternative battle and boss BGM.